# Add a property from one object, as a property in another object

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm trying to practice two concepts with my code below; the array `filter()` function, and to use it to grab a property from one object, and add it as a property in another.

I made two objects, `teachers` and `students`. I'm trying to use filter to add students to the teachers, so that each teacher will have a `teacher.student` property.

One of the teachers have two students, so ideally teacher.student is an array of objects.

Basically I'm trying to turn, for example:

```
teachers[2] = {name: 'Melissa', class: 'English'}
```

into

```
teachers[2] = {name: 'Melissa', class: 'English', students:[{name:'Mike'},{name:'Janet'}]}
```

In my solution below, `teachers[2]` only adds Janet, but ignores Mike.

I'd appreciate it if the suggestions could be a tweak of what I have (so that I can learn at my pace), and also if possible, a secondary simpler/shorter solution just so I could get an understanding of more efficient ways to approach this. I suppose this could be achieved without filter, but I just needed to use it to get comfortable using it.

Thanks in advance!

```
const teachers = [ 
  {name: 'James', class: 'Computer Science'},
  {name: 'Thomas', class: 'Biology'},
  {name: 'Melissa', class: 'English'}
];

const students = [
  {name: 'Mike', teacher: 'Melissa'},
  {name: 'Janet', teacher: 'Melissa'},
  {name: 'Elliot', teacher: 'Thomas'},
  {name: 'Gabe', teacher: 'James'},
]

const assignStudentsToTeachers = teachers.map((teacher) => {

  const filterStudents = students.filter((student) => {
    return teacher.name === student.teacher;
  });

  const filterStudentNames = filterStudents.map((student) => {
    for(let property in student){
      if(property === 'name'){
        teacher.students = [{'name': student[property]}];
      }
    }
  });
});

console.log(teachers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const a = teachers.map(t=>( 
  {...t, 
   students: students
     .filter(s => s.teacher === t.name)
     .map(s=>({name:s.name})) 
  }
));
```

Comment: Thank you. This puts the names inside an array e.g. `['Gabe']`. How would you turn it into `[{name: 'Gabe'}]`;? And what does spreading the operator do in your return, how does that work with the students object in your return?

Comment: To return object with name you can use studs.map(s=>({name:s.name}))

Comment: I review my post: I hope it is what you ask

Comment: Hey, this works and is exactly the result I'm looking for. I was wondering, how would this look like without the spread operator? Sorry for the follow up. I created this problem for practice, and your code looks really efficient. But I havent written a code with spread operator before, nor have I wrapped an object the way you do. I guess I'm looking for a more 'digestible' solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to return a new array instead alter the original teachers array, take a look on this example:

```js
const teachers = [ 
  {name: 'James', class: 'Computer Science'},
  {name: 'Thomas', class: 'Biology'},
  {name: 'Melissa', class: 'English'}
];

const students = [
  {name: 'Mike', teacher: 'Melissa'},
  {name: 'Janet', teacher: 'Melissa'},
  {name: 'Elliot', teacher: 'Thomas'},
  {name: 'Gabe', teacher: 'James'},
]

const assignStudentsToTeachers = teachers.map((teacher) => {

  const filterStudents = students.filter((student) => teacher.name === student.teacher);
  teacher.students = filterStudents.reduce((acc, student) => {
  acc.push(student.name)
  return acc;
}, [])
  return teacher

});

console.log(assignStudentsToTeachers);
```

Comment: Thank you. I did this too, but it also takes the teacher property as well. So `teachers[0].students = [{name:'Gabe'},{teacher:'James'}]`.  But I only want to grab the name, not the teacher.

Comment: Ok then you can use a reducer, take a look at my ansewer updated. @g